# How to return a body from another request

Tags: go

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347", nil)
req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.patch")
if err != nil {
    check(err)
}
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
ctxt.JSON(http.StatusOK, body)
```

Here I need to send api response from body of github api. But here I'm getting the following error:

> "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

Comment: You get an error with `ioutil.ReadAll`, but you did not handle the error. What is the error?

Comment: And whichline do you get `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`?

Comment: Naming a *request* as `resp` is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will solve your issues.

```
client := &http.Client{}
apiURL := "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347"
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", apiURL, nil)
if err != nil {
    check(err)
}
req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.patch")
response, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    check(err)
}
defer response.Body.Close()
contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
if err != nil {
    check(err)
}
ctxt.JSON(http.StatusOK, string(contents))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new GET request with a nil body. See the function signature for http.NewRequest

```
func NewRequest(method, url string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error)
```

so when you access resp.Body, of course it's going to be nil.

Also, http.NewRequest just returns a request, it doesn't actually perform it.

To actually make the GET request with your request, you need to pass it to a http client's `Do` method. Like so:

```
response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(resp)
```

EDIT: I would also add that naming your request as `resp` is confusing. I would recommend renaming the variable to `req` or `request`